# Bash script exit status to account for a git reset

Tags: git, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, exit-code

I have a script for deploying AWS beanstalk applications. Early parts of the script modify a handful of files based on the environment I'm deploying:

```
if [[ $enviro == qa ]] || [[ $enviro == staging ]]; then
  sed -i '' 's/'$app'.config/'$app'-'$enviro'.config/g' .ebextensions/0006_file.config
  git add .ebextensions/0006_file.config && git commit -m " for deploy only - will be (soft) reset "
fi
```

The last bit of my script reverts that with:

```
if [[ $enviro == qa ]] || [[ $enviro == staging ]]; then
  git reset --soft HEAD~1
  git reset HEAD .ebextensions/0006_file.config
  git checkout .ebextensions/0006_file.config
fi
```

However in between those two blocks I have the actual deploy line:

```
eb deploy $app-$enviro --label $current_date-$current_user --timeout 30 -v
```

What I'd like to do is write an if/then statement that exits the script if the 'eb deploy' block fails with exit code=1 but also does the git reset. If the script 'eb deploy' block succeeds I:

```
echo "Congratulations, you've deployed $branch to $enviro"
```

I can't tell but I may be overthinking this. I'm open to suggestions. My guess is that my second block will have to have another [[ ]] that sets the rc=$?

Thoughts?

Comment: Is that git repository checked out by the image being deployed or is that local config for eb?

Comment: it's a local config for eb.

Comment: Then why are you checking it in to git at all?

Comment: @EtanReisner being a relative noob to aws/eb this was the direction i was pointed when we initially stood up our environments. we check it in so other people can work on file. if there's a better way i'm all ears.

Comment: You make a change to a local file, check it in to git locally (but don't push it so it isn't available in any other repository) then run the tool that uses the local config file and then when you are all done you revert the repo so that the commit never existed in the first place (isn't in the branch's history anymore). Is that about right?

Comment: that's exactly correct.

Comment: Then I see no reason to involve git here at all. Just make the local change, run the `eb` command then use `git checkout` or `git reset --hard` or whatever to undo/overwrite the local changes.

Comment: eb won't use any changes unless they are committed locally.

Comment: How does that work? Does it do a checkout from the local directory into some other directory to fetch them? Or does it just go a "dirty" work-tree check and fail to work in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Trap' put me down the right road but I needed to add a function to complete the process.

```
function clean_up {
  if [[ $enviro == qa ]] || [[ $enviro == staging ]] || [[ $enviro == staging2 ]]; then
    git reset --soft HEAD~1
    git reset HEAD .ebextensions/0006_file.config
    git checkout .ebextensions/0006_file.config
  fi
}
fi
trap clean_up EXIT
```

Comment: the first argument to `trap` is the code to run; if you look at my answer, you'll see it's a single multiline string.  You could put anything in there and it would work, but the function is probably cleaner.

Comment: @MarkReed -- yep it definitely helped. my reputation isn't at 15 yet so I can't upvote your suggestion but it was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some code that you want to run when the script exits, even if it exits early, you can do that with `trap`.

```
# this code will get run when the script exits, whether via `exit` or falling
# off the bottom of the script
trap '
    git reset --whatever
' EXIT
```

Comment: Thanks I'll give this a shot and report back.

Comment: got this back: trap: usage: trap [-lp] [arg signal_spec ...]

Comment: I had to fix it by using a [function](https://gist.github.com/hobakill/0a3813f74c0288b04603).